# How do I "briefly but clearly comment my choice of research area(s) of interest"?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application

I am filling [McGill's Area of Research and Applicant Profile Form](https://www.mcgill.ca/ece/files/ece/arap_form.pdf) for admission to the Electrical Engineering M.Eng. program. I'm not sure how I should answer this (the 2nd field):

"For the specified research area(s) of interest, briefly but clearly comment on your choice. Further, if you have specified a supervisor(s), state why he or she would be your preferred mentor."

I have described my areas of interest and how I developed those interests and relevant experiences, in the previous space provided. I'm not sure what exactly should "comment" on. Do they expect me to write about, say, what Intelligent Systems is?

Comment: My best guess is that the previous field is asking *what* you want to research, and this  second field is asking *why*.  But I agree that it is not completely clear, and I endorse D. Gray's suggestion to contact them for clarification.

Comment: Frankly I suspect they want a very basic statement for easy glancing "I want to work with Prof Y because they have experience working with spicy electricity and wall plugs, which I did my bachelor's thesis on" (I don't know what EEs do)

Answer (score 1):

You should call them and ask about the distinction - it would be a far better answer as opposed to third party information on the forum. That’s honestly the best way you can resolve the confusion.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to upload this in a few hours. So, I'll have to take a guess.